# How to run more than 24 values in the visual foxpro in the "In" clause?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am using foxpro 5.0

I am having more than 3000 records to run a query.For example my query is

```
delete from mytable.dbf where fieldname not in (1,2,3,......3909)
```

It wont execute.Because foxpro allow only 24 records in the In clause.How can I execute this query?
Any simplification ideas.

Comment: Insert the records into a temporary table and run a delete using a join.  Or delete them in batches of 24.  Or maybe "... where fieldname not in (1,2,...,24) and fieldname not in (25,26,..48) and..."

Comment: I wrote like this `delete  from table1.dbf a join table2.DBF b on b.field  ! =a.field but it throws an error` But i gor the result for `select a.* from table1.dbf a join table2 b on b.field=a.fields` any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code demonstrates how you can delete records in one table based on the records in another table.

```
CREATE CURSOR Table1 (pk I)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(5)

CREATE CURSOR Table2 (pk I)
INSERT INTO Table2 (pk) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO Table2 (pk) VALUES(4)


DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.pk IN (SELECT Table2.pk FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try investigating the SYS(3055) function which allows you to adjust the complexity allowed in FOR and WHERE clauses.

However I would get the list of fieldname values that you want to keep into a temporary cursor, say called '_keep' and then do:

```
Delete From mytable where fieldname not in (select fieldname from _keep)
Use In Select("_keep")
```